# Is it possible to validate @Transient field in Spring Data REST?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have my entity with few fields and one of them with `@Transient` annotation.

```
class Entity {
   private String id;
   ...
   @Transient
   private String field;
}
```

And I have next problem with validation. When I try to `rejectValue` for that field I'm getting next exception: `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'field' of bean class [com.test.Entity]: Bean property 'field' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

I've found a place where exception is thrown `org.springframework.data.rest.core.ValidationErrors` 
we have there two lines:

```
PersistentProperty<?> property = entity.getPersistentProperty(PropertyAccessorUtils.getPropertyName(segment));

if (property == null) {
    throw new NotReadablePropertyException(source.getClass(), propertyName);
}
```

So it's possible to `rejectValue` only for persistent properties?
Any ideas how to overcome it?

Comment: I'm asking myself the same question. Why limit validation to persistent properties? There should at least be a way to configure SDR to use default validation.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case the field is sent by my custom controller to create an entity in a third-party system (thus it being Transient and not stored in the DB). 

The problem I have is the same as reported here: the validation framework doesn't allow reporting on that field as it Transient.